# ASM x86 relative JMP

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I'm doing some ASM code in a C code with the **asm** function.

My environment is DVL with gcc version 3.

Hi need to make a JMP to a relative address like %eip+0x1f.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

x86 supports a short jump (JMP, opcode EB + 1 byte relative address) which should do what you want.

In most assemblers (including gcc's inline asm IIRC) you can just put a label where you want to jump to, and use `jmp mylabel` and let the assember figure out the correct opcode and relative address for the jump.

Comment: I've just tried this out in GCC, and it does work (jumping to labels). But you beat me to the post!

Comment: for gcc inline assembly: what about without labels? __asm__("jmp short 0x3F"); doesn't seem to wirk for example. any solution?

Comment: @GalDude33: you could always encode it manually with `.byte`, but I think you can use `jmp  . + 0x3F` to jump forward 0x3F bytes from the *start* of the `jmp` instruction (not the end; you're not giving the rel8 directly, `.` is the address of the start of the current instruction so it's still basically a label+offset.  Normally you'd want to use a `.L` local label, or a numbered label like `1:` / `jmp 1b` to reference the first `1:` label in the backwards direction.)